# Setting up a VPN on Windows Server 2003

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, vpn

I set up a VPN on my server, everything seems okay but when I connect to it from Mac (didn't try windows) I can connect, I can send data and from the server I see that it receives it but it does not send any data back...

Did you ever happened to see this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Not even close to enough info to answer: is there a firewall, are the ports open on the firewall, can you connect from behind the fw, any event log errors on the server, does it work from a PC -if not what are the event log errors on the PC, what errors are logged on the Mac, how are you checking/seeing the "receive but no send" -Wireshark?, etc.

Comment: I know this is not an answer and you'll better solve your problem...
But if you happen to be in a dead end I've solved the vpn problem in a couple of clicks using Zeroshell: simply great.

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to say for certain due to the lack of details in the question but it sounds like a routing problem to me.

If you're VPN subnet is different than your LAN subnet you'll need to add a route on your LAN's default gateway that sends traffic for the VPN subnet to the VPN server so that the traffic can properly be routed back.